# How to change the default terminal beep frequency of the PC speaker?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, c

I want to change the default sound frequency of`SND_BELL`*(which is used when`\a`or BEL or ^G is printed on the screen)* to higher values *(the current default is around 750Hz)*.
Of course this turn to need a full programming solution.

The problem is I don't understand how the`int value`in[`pcspkr_event()`](https://github.com/andikleen/linux-misc/blob/lto-3.16/drivers/input/misc/pcspkr.c)is converted from a given frequency to a suitable value when used with`SND_TONE`.  So I don't understand how`value=1000`does render a 750Hz beep.

```
switch (code) {
    case SND_BELL: if (value) value = 1000; // changing this line would change the default beep frequency, but why 1000 does 750Hz tone????
    case SND_TONE: break; // with SND_TONE the value variable is already computed, so do nothing
    default: return -1;
}
```

Because the same function implement`SND_TONE`I thought it was a good idea to get what does call it, So I would be able to find the function which convert the frequency. However, the backtrace doesn't tell the function name which call [pcspkr_event](https://github.com/andikleen/linux-misc/blob/lto-3.16/drivers/input/misc/pcspkr.c) and it appeared the conversion is still not done in the function which call it *(`ìnput_handle_event()`)*.
I also couldn't find any documentation on how to use speaker when there is no Operating System.

So what is the frequency the relation between the frequency and the value of the`value`variable`?

Comment: This require a full programming question and a full programming answer, but the initial problem is I want to change the default [beep frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PC_speaker "echo -e "\a" bash command or man 3 beep"). So I thought it was better to ask here than on stackoverflow. Feel free to migrate it.

Answer (score 0):

The beep of the PC has a looong history. To understand it's use you have to know where it comes from. All PCs have a crystal (which originally was used to derive the clock of the CPU and the color frequency for the video output). This value was 14.318 MHz (and change)... Divided by 3, this gave the CPU frequency (4.77 MHz in the original PC), and divided by 4, it gave the (NTSC) 3.58 MHz color carrier.

The 4.77 was then divide by 4 to give 1.19 MHz... This was divided by 65536 to give the original clock signal (18 Hz), and divided by another - variable - value to give the beep. This is the int value you have to program!

So, 14.31818 MHz / 12 = 1.193182MHz (1193182 Hz).
1193182 /1000 = 1193 will give you a 1000Hz tone.

The code you reference calls PIT_TICK_RATE (see http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/timex.h?v=3.2#L277), which is defined in this:

```
* The clock frequency of the i8253/i8254 PIT */
#define PIT_TICK_RATE 1193182ul
```

Of course all this works only as root admin...

Comment: So are you trying to convince me that the default frequency of SND_BELL isn't at [750Hz](http://linux.die.net/man/1/beep "As a general ballpark, the regular terminal beep is around 750Hz.") but at 1193Hz? What it you point about root? Kernel modules are user agnostic.

Comment: Nope... If you say 750, I believe you... In that case, the BIOS probably programmed it at 1193182/750 = 1590. In fact, in one listing I have here, the factor was programmed to be 1331, to generate 886 Hz. There is no real standard for the beep tone.

Comment: This [file](https://github.com/andikleen/linux-misc/blob/lto-3.16/drivers/input/misc/pcspkr.c#L37) give 750Hz with mode=SND_BELL on all PC.

Comment: About the root access. Yes, but I see there are 'out' instructions to re-program the timer. These instructions are protected, and only root can access them.

Comment: Added a reference to my previous reply... Which shows where PIT_... from you file is defined.

Comment: and why do you keep insisting that root is required. Did you ever tried`echo -e "\a"`on bash command prompt? This is kernel code for module. There is no conception of separate users, nor privileged instructions since the kernel run at ring 0. Perhaps you didn’t paid attention to the tags?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22812/discussion-between-jcoppens-and-user2284570).

Comment: : Ok you’re right, terminal bells use SND_TONE.